# How to set up my own full-featured certificate authority?

Tags: linux, security, ssl-certificate, openssl, rsa

I'd like to set up a certificate authority, which I can then import to all the company's browsers and systems to get rid of all those nasty client warnings when using HTTPS or SSL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [TinyCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCA), a graphical front-end for [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) that lets you manage the tasks of a certificate authority.

Beware that the TinyCA [website](http://www.sm-zone.net) seems hard to reach at times.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using [OpenCA](http://www.openca.org/) and here is the [install guide](http://mm.cs.dartmouth.edu/wiki/index.php/Installing_OpenCA).  This is a full fledge PKI suite,  which includes an [OCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) server to immediately revoke certificates.  It also has a [PKI Resource Protocol](http://www.redhat.com/certificate_system/) server.  I have personally used OpenCA and it is what you want.

If you really like RedHat and Java then you might want to go with [RedHat Certificate System](http://www.redhat.com/certificate_system/).

Comment: http://mm.cs.dartmouth.edu/wiki/index.php/Installing_OpenCA link is no longer working as of 10/14/2013 or sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this: http://novosial.org/openssl/ca/

And for the entire work flow:  http://novosial.org/openssl/

Comment: Links are broken as of 5/11

Answer (score 0):

You can craft your own certificates with `openssl` command line tool.

It is possible to generate the `root` certificate, hence the (sub-)certificates you need.

You can use the following tool, simplifying the whole process: https://github.com/auino/your-own-ssl-certificate-authority